# How can I make to work padding, which is scaling by browser's width, when centered a content using `diplay: table;`?

Tags: html, css, centering

^As title says^. I need to scale padding by a browser's width. I tried this:

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#center{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.box{
  padding: 25%;
  background: #000;
  color: white;
}

h1{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="center">
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't work. Is there any way I can do it? I want to center the div using `display: table;`,  not using flexbox or `position: absolute`. Thanks.

Comment: For padding use `vw` and `vh` values, it is percent of viewport width and height. You can read [this article](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `vw` which is percent of viewport width.

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#center{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.box{
  padding: 5vw;
  background: #000;
  color: white;
}

h1{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="center">
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

[See fiddle here you can resize the viewable area and see the padding size change.](https://jsfiddle.net/76pghoL0/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use flex-box to make vertically center.

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center
}
```

Comment: Read my post again, I do NOT want to use flexbox.